# How to prove that $ P(f)\ast \delta=0 $ (P is the d'Alembertian)

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory, distribution-theory

I am reading Distribution Theory by Friedlander and joshi (specifically chapter 7- coordinate transformations and pullbacks).

I find it hard to prove the next claim:

Show that if  $P(\partial)= \partial_4^2-\partial_1^2-\partial_2^2-\partial_3^2$
is the definition of the D'alembertian then  $
 P(f)\ast \delta=0
$
where f is $C^\infty(X)$ and
X is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$

Any clue?

Comment: Seems strange since $u*\delta=u$ for every distribution $u$.

Comment: I thought that maybe somehow the differentiation will move to delta dirac. find it really difficult.

Comment: Also, if $X \subseteq \mathbb{R},$ what does $\partial_1,\partial_2,\partial_3,\partial_4$ mean? Shouldn't $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}^4$ with Minkowskian "metric"?